# ionic start project_name sidemenu when EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, node-sass

I want to create a new project. I set up all my packages. But when I create the project I get the error I mentioned below. How can I resolve it?

I unloaded the ionic packages first and then uploaded them again. but I could not find any solution.

```
✖ Running command - failed!
```

[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):

```
    > fsevents@1.1.3 install 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/fsevents
    > node install

    [fsevents] Success: 
    "/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v59-darwin-x64/fse.node" 
    is installed via remote

    > node-sass@4.5.3 install 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    Unable to save binary 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-59 : 
    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
    '/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
         at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:905:18)
         at sync 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
         at Function.sync 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
         at checkAndDownloadBinary 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
         at Object.<anonymous> 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
         at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
         at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
       errno: -13,
       code: 'EACCES',
       syscall: 'mkdir',
       path: '/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
    > node lib/post_install.js


    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: /usr/local/bin/node 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild 
    --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= 
    --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
    gyp verb cli   
    '/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@9.2.1 | darwin | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the 
    PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at 
    getNotFoundError 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E 
    (/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at 
    FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the 
    PATH
    gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
    gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; 
    print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
    gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to 
    host node version: 9.2.1
    gyp verb command install [ '9.2.1' ]
    gyp verb install input version string "9.2.1"
    gyp verb install installing version: 9.2.1
    gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already 
    installed
    gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check 
    "installVersion"
    gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
    gyp verb install version is good
    gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 9.2.1
    gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: 
    /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/build
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
    '/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass/build'
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
    "/Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
    "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" 
    "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/CAN/Desktop/orbetas/node_modules/node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
    additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/CAN/.npm/_logs/2017-12-19T09_06_58_843Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You need to run the command as administrator/root

Comment: But This is what I have created, and I create the new project on the desktop @NullDev

Comment: can you please put `ionic info` to your question?

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala okey. @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0  Node : v8.9.3 npm  : 5.5.1 backend : pro
Error with ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/package.json file:FILE_NOT_FOUND @ionic/app-scripts : not installed ANDROID_HOME : not set

Comment: I think the installation of ionic is not done properly